# Inside a promise I want to assign value(the value itself comes from some another promise ) to a variable which will be used outside of that promise

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, async-await

In my Firestore DB, I have two collections `books` and `categories`. In categories collection all documents have only one field i.e. `name`, and in `books` collection the document contains multiple field and one of them is `type` which is an array of datatype `DocumentRef`, which means each document in books can have multiple values of categories-name.

Now, for each document in the `books` collection, I want to get all the values of associated categories name in a single string.

This is what I have till now.

```js
database
    .collection("books")
    .get()
    .then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
            renderTypes(doc);
        });
    });

/** The renderTypes function **/
renderTypes = doc => {
    let typeArrayRef = doc.data().type; // assigning the array of documentRefs

    console.log("total elements in types array is ", typeArrayRef.length);
    promiseVar = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        typeList = " ";
        // looping through each items inside the array
        typeArrayRef.forEach(type => {
            type.get().then(res => {
                typeList = typeList + " " + res.data().name;
            });
            // unccommenting this line gives a mixed output (out of order)
            // console.log(`String containing all the types are ${ type }`);
        });
        resolve(type); // resolving with type string
    });

    promiseVar.then(type => {
        console.log("Inside the then of promiseVar", type);
    });
};
```

Now the output I get is :

```
total elements in types array is 6 
total elements in types array is 3
total elements in types array is 1 

Inside the then of promiseVar
Inside the then of promiseVar 
Inside the then of promiseVar
```

Nothing is being printed in the last three lines but logging it inside the `promiseVar` gives the output but is mixed (i.e. there is no fixed order).

It seems like the `promiseVar` is resolving straightaway. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Is it OK for you to use ES7 [Async/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)?

Comment: Yes there is no problem using asyn/await

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to aggregate a list of async values, you can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and then compute the result. In your case, it may look something like this:

```js
renderTypes = doc => {
    const typeArrayRef = doc.data().type; // assigning the array of documentRefs
    console.log("total elements in types array is ", typeArrayRef.length);

    const promiseVar = Promise
      .all(typeArrayRef.map(type => type.get()))
      .then(types => {
        const typeList = types.map(type => type.data().name).join(' ');
        return typeList;
      });

    promiseVar.then(type => {
        console.log("Inside the then of promiseVar", type);
    });
};
```

First, we create a list of promises and wait for all of them to resolve. When it's ready, `types` is the list of all responses. Chaining `.then` makes `promiseVar` resolve the desired result. We can make it even simpler with `await` keyword:

```js
renderTypes = async doc => {
    const typeArrayRef = doc.data().type; // assigning the array of documentRefs
    console.log("total elements in types array is ", typeArrayRef.length);

    const types = await Promise.all(typeArrayRef.map(type => type.get()));
    const typeList = types.map(type => type.data().name).join(' ');

    // Not really _inside_ now.
    console.log("Inside the then of promiseVar", typeList);
};
```